# Is a boxed-mix cake sturdy enough to construct a sphere?

Tags: baking, cake

I am going to attempt to make a (roughly) spherical cake. The plan is bake two hemispheres, then put them together into a sphere. However, I'm rather concerned about the stability of the cake.

I would prefer to use a boxed mix (to keep the overall preparation simpler) -- but I don't think that "moist" and "fluffy" cake is going to be able to hold itself up in a bowl shape `\_/` let alone support another cake set on top of it.

Is there a way to stablize or "firm up" a boxed mix to make a denser cake, or should I look for a from-scratch recipe that's intended for sculpture or building?

Comment: How big of a sphere?

Comment: I'm flexible -- if a small sphere is the only way I can get it to work, fine, but the child who's requested it wants it to be about 12" (30 cm) in diameter.

Comment: Are you going to do a full "construction", dowels and all, or are you just going to stick two halves together?

Comment: A lighter cake might actually hold its shape better. Swiss roll sponge is pretty tough for example, and weights very little.

Comment: @Stephie I hope just two cakes. I have no experience with more structural assembly and little time to practice...

Comment: If you have a metal bowl(s) in which to bake the cake, it will make final assembly easier. 'Glue' the two halves with frosting, and crumb coat the entire sphere before a final coating.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to increase the density of a box-cake mix.  Add the number of eggs in the direction, but add two extra egg yolks. Instead of the water, use the same amount of whole milk.

Another method is to add a package of instant pudding, and many mixes have a recipe for this right on the box. To each box mix, use a 3.4 ounce package of instant pudding, 4 eggs, 1 cup water (or milk) and reduce the amount of vegetable oil to 1/3 cup.

And one I found years ago, who posts on [Cake Central as doreen1092](https://www.cakecentral.com/u/375003/doreen1092), offered this: to each box cake mix, add 1/2 cup sour cream, 2 eggs, 1/4 cup sugar, and 8 ounces cream cheese. I beat the cream cheese, then add the eggs and sugar, the sour cream and, lastly, the mix.